# Conditionals and adverb clauses

Tags: adverbial-phrases, conditionals

> (1) If I ate too much food now, I wouldn't be able to eat anything else when my pizza **arrives** in 30 minutes.

Is the **arrives** correct here?

---

> (2) If I didn't sleep now, I would look terrible when I **go** to work tomorrow.

Is the **go** correct here?

---

> (3) If I didn't wake up when my alarm clock **goes off**, I would be late for work.

Is the **goes off** correct here?

---

> (4) If I didn't wake up when my alarm clock **goes off**, I would be scolded by my boss because she always **tells** us not to be late.

Is the **goes off** correct here?

Is the **tells** correct here?

---

So in cases of conditionals, do we just use tenses in adverb clauses normally depending on what we are trying to say, right?

Comment: The verbs you are querying are all fine, but I would use _eat_ and _won't_ for No. 1 and _don't_ and _will_ for the others.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for your answer. Do you mean, if I use second conditional with verb tenses like the ones in the examples, they are correct, but you would recommend I use first conditional in the examples?

Comment: It seems much more natural to me. If you're expecting a pizza delivery in half an hour, the decision whether or not to eat now is immediate, not a speculation about an imaginary situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. question - Yes, **arrives** is used correctly.
2. question - Yes, **go** is used correctly.
3. question - No, **qoes off** is not used correctly because the sentence indicates that it is in the past when you say "didn't". If you swapped the "didn't" with "don't", it would be correct.
4. question - As for **goes off**, it's the same issue as in question 3, but **tells** is used correctly.

Comment: If I want to use these conditionals as present unreal conditionals, will the tense use in the verbs in bold in my examples be correct?

Comment: @vincentlin Yes that would work